# HTML Converting a table to HTML layout

Tags: html

So I have a table that I want to convert to a html layout because it's much easier to control, but I don't really know whats the best way of doing it, can you give me a few ideas.

Example of one of the tables.

```
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; border: medium none;" align="left" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td style="border: medium none;">
        <span style="font-size: 8pt;">Test2</span>
    </td>
    <td style="border: medium none;">
        <span style="font-size: 8pt;">Test3<br/></span>
    </td>
    <td style="border: medium none;">
        <span style="font-size: 8pt;">Test4<br/></span>
    </td>
    <td style="border: medium none;">
        <span style="font-size: 8pt;">Test5</span>
    </td>
    <td style="border: medium none;">
        <span style="font-size: 8pt;">Test6<br/></span>
    </td>
    <td style="border: medium none;">
        <span style="font-size: 8pt;">Test7<br/></span>
    </td>
    <td style="border: medium none;">
        <span style="font-size: 8pt;">Test8<br/></span>
    </td>
    <td style="border: medium none;">
        <span style="font-size: 8pt;">Test9<br/></span>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What are your layout goals?

Comment: I want to have only 4 rows and infinite columns

Answer (score 1):

Each `<tr>` denotes a row. Each `<td>` denotes a column. See the example for a 4 row, multi column table.

```
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; border: medium none;" align="left" width="100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td style="border: medium none;">
            <span style="font-size: 8pt;">...</span>
        </td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
        ...etc...
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="border: medium none;">
            <span style="font-size: 8pt;">...</span>
        </td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
        ...etc...
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="border: medium none;">
            <span style="font-size: 8pt;">...</span>
        </td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
        ...etc...
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="border: medium none;">
            <span style="font-size: 8pt;">...</span>
        </td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
        ...etc...
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```